# Show/Hide Sprites & Texts in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I have an image and some text that I want to show/hide:

```
overlay = this.game.add.image( 0, 0, this.custom_texture.generateTexture() );
overlay_text = this.game.add.text( 0, 0, 'TESTING 123', style );
```

I tried the `destroy()` function, but I wasn't able to bring them back, plus I don't think it's necessary to destroy them if I simply want to hide & show them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's more intuitive than I thought it would be. 
To hide:

```
overlay.visible = false;
overlay_text.visible = false;
```

To Show:

```
overlay.visible = true;
overlay_text.visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

In one Liner, we can toggle hide/show.

```
overlay.visible= !overlay.visible;
overlay_text.visible = !overlay_text.visible;
```